# How do you remove ‘grease’ stains from grey leather boots

Tags: cleaning, shoes, stain

I bought an expensive ankle boot but I somehow got some darker grey spots on them. I expect it maybe an oily substance and so I tried using dish soap and scrubbed them but it left a darker scrubbed patch on the affected part. I also tried using hot water and cloth and it didn’t work. Please provide me a hack for removing the same.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I have this sort of oily stain on clothes I use pure orange oil. In Australia it is readily available in supermarkets. Rub it in and then wash in washing machine. Almost always works. With shoes I would do the same on a trial stain  and then get some warm soapy water and remove the orange oil and stain and then let it dry. This is a suggestion but I admit I have never used it for that application. Orange oil is very versatile.  I have used it to remove paint scratches on a car where the scratch was the result of foreign paint being deposited on the car i.e. the car backed into a white post and the paint scratch was mostly from the post.

Comment: Is Orange Oil the oil from the fruit oranges or is it a commercial name for a different kind of oil?

Comment: It is extracted from oranges. The one I buy in Australia is Orange Power See http://awareenvironmental.com.au/product/sticky-spot-goo-dissolver/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you the following methods to remove oily stain. The following are applied generally for greasy stains.

- Acting quickly upon incident, clean leather with a microfiber cloth or with talcum powder. Instead of rubbing, try blotting gently and it would be better to use lint free micro fiber cloth.
- Identify the pattern of leather and try to dismiss the stain by blotting from outside the stain to inside.
- You can use baking soda, table salt to prepare a homemade cleaning solution. Apply the same.

Answer (score 0):

Corn starch. Put it on any grease or oil And it turns into like a texture you can just wipe off, then coconut oil to give em a nice shine